# Are the Boeing CST-100 Starliner and Orion MPCV interchangeable at any level?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, orion-spacecraft, cst-100

Although the [Boeing CST-100 Starliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CST-100_Starliner) and the [Orion MPCV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_(spacecraft)) are designed for different missions (LEO vs beyond LEO), one might imagine a mission which could be served by either vehicle. Presumably, both will be equipped with the same type of docking adapter, but can either be mated to and launched on the same booster type? Do they have compatible physical/electrical mountings/interconnections? Or do the different mission types and therefore booster requirements preclude the need for any such standardization?

Comment: This is a very tiny, picky request, sorry! Could you add links to what a CST-100 and MPCV are? I haven't a clue, and I can't even select-right-click their names in the title because the title is also one big active link. Or, at the very least, repeat the names of the objects in the text of the question where I can get at them by select-right-clicking? Right now I have to either remember their names when I open up a new search tab, or type them into a text file in a different application, select/copy then open a new tab, then paste. Thanks!

Comment: Well, an Orion spacecraft test article was launched on a Delta IV Heavy, and the CST-100 is intended to be launched on any one of Atlas, Delta, and Vulcan (and possibly F9), so it's *possible* that they could share launchers in the future (depends on the future of the SLS and Orion programs). However, the CST-100 is absolutely not designed for cis-lunar missions (inadequate heat shield, for one thing), and I'd consider using Orion for LEO missions to be massive overkill and a waste of money.

Answer (score 2):

Short principle-based answer: **Yes**

They both use a [Low Impact Docking System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Docking_System), so what one could dock with the other could too. For that matter, they could dock with eachother.

Here's the principle based part; Ever tried to hook up an old monitor to  a new computer? Maybe you have DVI cable for your TV but an HDMI cable on your cable box? Adapters are cheap and easy to come by for these consumer grade items.

Same goes for your rocket. Granted, you probably can't buy an Atlas-to-Orion adapter online, but space agencies employ lots of bright and talented people. Engineers exist to solve these problems.

Also, vehicle assembly isn't as simple as screwing your payload into a launcher. You're not so much loading it onto a launch vehicle as you are building it into the launch vehicle. Again, your engineers are going to earn their keep - it's part of their job to make sure all the electronics and power hookups are linked together properly.