# Boeing starliner launch vehicle

Tags: nasa, ula, orion-spacecraft

Boeing and Spacex is practically in race to human flight launch first. It's rocket-ULA Atlas-V have excellent record already in industry. But the Starliner aerodynamic problems aerodynamic/mass due to changes in design/size and water landing(Is orion immune to this?) . How is Starliner doing and human rating of Atlas-V doing so far are they still planing for 2018-2019 launch ferry window?

Comment: Related: [Why are the very reliable rockets Atlas V and Ariane V not rated for human flight?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/4784/4660)

Comment: What "starliner aerodynamic problem"?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? If you're asking why the Atlas V isn't already human-rated, the linked question covers that. If you're asking about the differences between Orion, CST-100, and Dragon, that's mostly covered in questions like [Reason for different “cone angles” of different space capsules?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/11975/13208), [How do the sizes of the various proposed manned capsules differ?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/8024/13208), and [Are the Boeing CST-100 Starliner and Orion MPCV interchangeable at any level?](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/17848/13208)

Comment: This really should be two questions. One about aerodynamics, and one about human-rating of Atlas-V. Also, since you mention a specific Starliner aerodynamic problem, you should say what it is, as Organic Marble pointed out. From how you say it in the question you seem to be asking about Orion aerodynamics, not Starliner.

Comment: It is good to see that you often edit your questions, but the edits don't add the information needed. If aerodynamic issues are in the news, then link to the news story and briefly explain what the issue is. Also, now that you have clarified, this is now 3 questions in one: Does Orion have the same aerodynamic issue? How is human-rating of Atlas V progressing? and How is aerodynamics of the Starliner on the Atlas V being handled? I am guessing a bit, i am still not sure from how it is phrased.

Comment: You have shown a lot of commitment, and i understand there is a language barrier, but there is really no way to get the answers you seek except to start taking the advice offered to you. Please narrow this to one question, explain that one question, and don't put anything else. If you have read something in the news, link to that story.

Comment: News story on human-rating of Atlas V: http://www.thespacereview.com/article/3048/1

Answer (score 4):

Presumably the aerodynamic problems with the Starliner are specific to its use with the Atlas V launcher. The 4.6m diameter of the capsule has to "neck down" onto the 3m upper stage of the Atlas, and the shape of that transition has significant aerodynamic effects.

Since Orion CEV is much too heavy for Atlas V, it will have a different set of problems. Orion's 5 meter diameter matches that of the DCSS-5 used with Delta IV Heavy, so it won't have that kind of "neck down" adapter, so it should be aerodynamically relatively trouble-free on that launcher.